# Prompt to unlock lock screen on custom notification click

Tags: android, notifications, lockscreen

I have a custom notification shown in the lock screen. I am using a broadcast pending intent to send a message to my app once the notification is clicked. Which later starts an activity in the broadcast receiver.

The problem is, once I click on the notification, it disappears from the lock-screen and the activity is launched behind the lock-screen. It does not ask the user to unlock the screen.

My requirement is to ask the user to unlock the screen as soon as the broadcast is sent by the notification's click event. How do I do that?

I could find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980389/how-to-open-ask-for-lock-screen-after-double-click-on-notification-android) question which looks like my problem. But unfortunately there is no answer.

Here is some code that explains the notification creation I did.

```
/**
 * Method to render Notification
 */
private void showNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    /* set mandatory stuff on builder */

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        notification.bigContentView = createCustomView(context);
    }

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(getNotificationId(), notification);
}

/**
 * Method to return notification click's PendingIntent
 */
private PendingIntent getNotificationClickIntent() {
    Intent bcIntent = new Intent(OPEN_APP);
    bcIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEEP_LINK_URL, getDeepLinkUrl());

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context, getReqCode(), bcIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
}

/**
 * Method to create custom view for notification
 */
private RemoteViews createCustomView(Context context) {
   RemoteViews customView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_layout);

   if (customView != null) {
        // set dat on views

        customView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.my_view, getNotificationClickIntent());
   }

   return customView;
}
```

Comment: did you eventually find a more elegant solution for this case?

Comment: @AmirUval I ended up using an intermediate activity which has no UI

Comment: Thanks. That's what I eventually did as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Activity intent in pending intent instead of Service or Broadcast

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                                 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Update:

In my case i use service.

```
private fun activityPendingIntent(context: Context, action: String? = null): PendingIntent {
    Timber.d("activityPendingIntent")
    val intent = Intent(context, DummyBackgroundActivity::class.java)
    action?.let { intent.action = action }
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, ACTIVITY_NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
}
```

DummyBackgroundActivity

```
class DummyBackgroundActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val service = Intent(this, BackgroundService::class.java)
        service.action = intent.action
        startService(service)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        finish()
    }
}
```

Service:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    Timber.d("onStartCommand intent = %s", intent?.action)
    when (intent?.action) {
       //Handle it 
    }

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY
}
```

I hope you replicate the same using Broadcast.

Comment: No. This can't be used in my case. My code is part of a library. In the library we will not know which activity needs to be started. Hence I am depending on the broadcasts now. In the receiver the client app who uses this library will implement the activity launching code.

Comment: @RahulRaveendran In your case, you can create a dummy activity and in onCreate broadcast the event and in onResume finish the activity. I have updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update man! but I had this idea in mind. Wanted to see if there is any other way to deal with this. Coz introducing an activity in between is not feasible at this point of time :(

Comment: @RahulRaveendran its ok, maybe my answer will help other.